# Infinite CSS3 Animation when hover ends

Tags: css, animation

I have some arrows image which are linked to kind of "Back to previous page".
I want to animate those arrows with a slight translation when hover it.
My trouble is when hover ends, the arrow instantly goes back to his initial state without any "transition".

Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks.

Here's my code :

```
@keyframes movingArrow {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-10%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.moving-arrow:hover img {
  animation: movingArrow 1s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help !

A friend helped me by pausing the animation when hover ends, it's not exactly what was targeted but this state is alright for me.

Using [anime.js](http://animejs.com) & this [codepen](http://codepen.io/viande/pen/MQrXaz)

```
 <body>

  <h3 class="moving-arrow">&larr; Back</h3>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>

</body>
```

--

```
const movingArrow = document.querySelector('.moving-arrow');

let animation = anime({
  targets: movingArrow,
  translateX: '-1%',
  direction: 'alternate',
  duration: 500,
  loop: true,
  easing: 'easeInCubic',
  autoplay: false
});

movingArrow.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  console.log("mouseover")
  animation.play()
})

movingArrow.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  console.log("onmouseleave", animation)
  animation.pause()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to show demo for you at codepen https://codepen.io/navdeepsingh/pen/oEwyqP Have a look

```js
const movingArrow = document.querySelector('.moving-arrow');
movingArrow.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  this.classList.remove('no-animation'); 
});
```

```css
.moving-arrow {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000 transparent #000 #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
@keyframes movingArrow {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  } 
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes movingArrowReset {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}

/* This you need */
.moving-arrow { 
  animation: movingArrowReset 1s;
}

.moving-arrow:hover {
  animation: movingArrow 1s infinite;
}
.no-animation {
  -webkit-animation: none !important;  
  animation: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="moving-arrow no-animation"></div>
```